# I used matplotlib, but the error message '<Figure size 720x576 with 0 Axes>' appeared with graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager, rc

f_name = font_manager.FontProperties(fname='C:/Windows/Fonts/HANBatangExt.ttf').get_name()
rc('font', family=f_name)
```

## 뛰기운동

```
plt.plot(run_before, run_after, 'ro-')
```

## 걷기운동

```
plt.plot(walk_before, walk_after, 'bo-')
plt.figure(figsize=((10,8)))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 10):

It is not an error but the output you see is due to the fact that you have used

```
plt.figure(figsize=((10,8)))
```

after `plt.plot`. Therefore, you first get a figure on you screen and a figure object is created by `plt.figure`. To get rid of it, you should first set the figure size before plotting, something like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=((10,8)))
plt.plot(run_before, run_after, 'ro-')
plt.plot(walk_before, walk_after, 'bo-')
plt.show()
```

There are other ways to set the figure size after plotting but since your code is fine enough, you are good to go with the above modification.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an Error it shows your figure dimensions. If you want to get rid of it  try using rcParams parameter

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,8)
```

Answer (score 2):

**It is not the error just a message that an image file is returned**

> If you are using the VS_code then

1. Click on the left side little **code** icon
2. Select Image/Png option this will make your graph visible

*If you havent seleced the Image/Png option then you might not be able to see the output*

[image: pic1]