# Using `matplotlib` to plot - <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've a huge data set with 158 columns and 3.1 million rows. I'm trying to plot univariate distibutions for that data set. Code is as given below.

```
dtf = pd.read_csv('hackathon_train_data1.csv')
dtf.head()
dtf.columns
```

Output was:

> Index(['visit_id', 'cod_order_nbr', 'cod_orig_ord_nbr', 'src_bu_id',
> 'int_ref_nbr', 'cod_orig_bu_id', 'cod_src_bu_id', 'onln_flg',
> 'sohf_ord_dt', 'cod_init',
> ...
> 'csat_guid_v42', 'visit_num', 'chat_drawer_rightrail_open',
> 'chat_unavailable', 'chat_portal', 'ishmximpressions', 'pagination_c40',
> 'chat_intent_flag', 'coupon_code_stp_v96', 'isbreadcrumbhit_flg'],
> dtype='object', length=157)

Then I assigned the one of the column names to `y` and plotted the graph. Column `cod_flg` has only 2 entries, `0` and `1`.

```
y = "cod_flg"  
ax = dtf[y].value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind="barh")
```

Output was:
[image: Graph]
Then I tried to refine it as,

```
totals= []
for i in ax.patches:
    totals.append(i.get_width())
total = sum(totals)
for i in ax.patches:
     ax.text(i.get_width()+.3, i.get_y()+.20, 
     str(round((i.get_width()/total)*100, 2))+'%', 
     fontsize=10, color='black')
ax.grid(axis="x")
plt.suptitle(y, fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

It threw me this error:

> Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes

Do I need to modify this line? `ax.text(i.get_width()+.3, i.get_y()+.20,  str(round((i.get_width()/total)*100, 2))+'%',  fontsize=10, color='black')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I used matplotlib, but the error message '<Figure size 720x576 with 0 Axes>' appeared with graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834616/i-used-matplotlib-but-the-error-message-figure-size-720x576-with-0-axes-app)

Comment: In that link, it says that we should set `figsize` first, I'm not using `figsize` in my code.

Comment: Are you sure it is an error, and not Jupyter just writing out the result of the last command?  Did you try putting all commands into the same cell?  Could you show the full error trace?

Comment: It isn't an error actually, jupyter is printing that. But that doesn't make sense unless there is some bug in my code, need help to figure out that

Answer (score 0):

try without plt.show() , if you are using Google Colab